# How to retrieve data from a database to an HTML list using C#?

Tags: sql

I'm using C# and the database management system is SQL server.

I have a database that contains a table called `tblPerson`, this table has several columns:

```
create table tblPerson
(
    personID int primary key not null identity,
    firstName nvarchar(50) not null,
    lastName nvarchar(50) not null,
    designation nvarchar(50) not null,
    salary int not null,
    email nvarchar(50) not null,
    phone bigint not null
)


create procedure spGetPersonDetails
@ID int
as 
begin
    select * from tblPerson where personID = @ID
end
```

I have inserted some sample data into this table and created a store procedure to retrieve the data from the database. Now I need to retrieve the data from this database and show it to an list element as shown below.

- First Name : some name
- Last Name : some name
- Designation : Engg..
- Salary : some amount
- Email : some email
- Phone : some phone number

Comment: What server side programming language you are trying to learn?

Comment: It is c# with SQL server

Comment: then I think you want to learn C# ASP.NET, I think [NerdDinner](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/free-asp-net-mvc-nerddinner-tutorial-now-in-html) tutorial will help you to start

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Let me go thorough this. will keep in touch..